# mongodb - ignore document if one of elements in array matches query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a user object in users colelction like below:

```
{
  "username": "bahramhasanov",
  "sessions": [
    {
      "time": "2018-12-10 12:30"
    },
    {
      "time": "2018-10-11 13:30"
    }
  ]}
```

Now I want to get users who does not have any session between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-15'. 
When I query with $elemMatch and $not I get bahramhasanov because he has a session out of this date range.

I used this query:

```
db.users.find({sessions:{$elemMatch: {"time": {$not:{$gt: ISODate('2018-10-01'),$lt: ISODate('2018-10-15')}}}}})
```

Comment: So what is your problem with that query?

Comment: I need ignore this user because he have a session between 01.10 - 15.10.2018

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971909/mongodb-mongoose-querying-an-array-of-objects-by-date check this out

Comment: Dear Ankit, This does not worked for me. Mongo version is 2.6

Comment: Try this `db.collection.find({
  sessions: {
    $not: {
      $elemMatch: {
        "time": {
          $gt: "2018-10-01",
          $lt: "2018-10-15"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})`

Comment: @Anthony, this returns user if he have a session out of range

Comment: How https://mongoplayground.net/p/jLY_aoi7vll?

Comment: Thanks Anthony. This worked. (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`$not`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) query operator in order to oppose the whole [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator not only with the `$lte` and the `$gte`

And also the time is in `String` not in `ISODate` format

```
db.collection.find({
  "sessions": {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "time": {
          "$gt": ISO("2018-12-17T20:00:00.000+0000"),
          "$lt": ISO("2018-12-17T20:00:00.000+0000")
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: my mongodb version is 2.6 and this trick does not work?
what is minimum requirement for this?

Comment: mongodb 2.6 is really out of date. You should update it

Comment: I have updated mongo to 3.6 but query does not work:

`{$and:[{promos:{$not:{$elemMatch:{time:{$gte:"2018-12-01",$lte:"2018-12-31"}}}}}]}`

Comment: what is the type of the `time`?

Comment: "time" : ISODate("2018-12-17T20:00:00.000+0000"),

Comment: I have predicted from your question and updated query: `{$and:[{promos:{$not:{$elemMatch:{time:{$gte:new ISODate("2018-12-01"),$lte:new ISODate("2018-12-31")}}}}}]}`

Comment: If your time is in ISODate then use ISODate and if your time is in string then use String. Nothing else

Answer (score 1):

To query users who do not have any session between a date range, you will need to query users who have sessions outside the date range and then query users who are not among them. In your query you get users who have sessions inside the date range, which will indeed return users who have sessions inside the date range and outside the date range and will not return users inside the date range. In terms of sets, let us consider

O = "the users having sessions outside the date range"

I = "the users having sessions inside the date range"

A = "all users"

O ∩ I = "the users having sessions inside and outside the date range"

O ∪ I = "the users having sessions inside or outside the date range"

Now, you need

A \ O and in order to do it, you will need to find O and then filter its items out from A.

Comment: thanks for great answer, but i need a single query for this :)

Comment: @BahramHasanov I am not an expert of MongoDB, hence my theoretic answer, because the math should work. I believe you should have the means to make this a single query, using subqueries. This might help you: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-perform-subqueries-in-MongoDB